# Foreign key constraint across tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, primary-key

I have tables A, B and C where there is a one-to-many relationship between B and A and B and C respectively.

[image: Simplified problem description]

I need a constraint that for every row of C `rowC.propertyC` is element of

`SELECT A.propertyA
 FROM A, B, C
 WHERE A.id_b = B.id AND B.id = rowC.id_b`

Now obviously I cannot define a constraint `FOREIGN KEY(propertyC) REFERENCES A(propertyA)` because the link with table `B` is missing.

Could introducing a fourth table that contains valid combinations of `B.id` and `propertyA` and adding that as a foreign key constraint to `C` be a solution maybe?

I am really not sure what to search for, pointers in any direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `a (propertyA, id_b)` and then a `FOREIGN KEY (propertyC, id_b) REFERENCES a (propertyA, id_b)`. And then you can remove the C -> B foreign key.

Comment: *"Could introducing a fourth table that contains valid combinations of B.id and propertyA ..?"* You  already have that, it's table A.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I currently use MySQL

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Exactly! I could not use a foreign key because there was no UNIQUE constraint! That should work now, thanks!

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I got carried away too quickly...Of course  `(propertyA, id_b)` is not UNIQUE in table `A` !

Comment: So you have other columns that are not shown.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ In fact I do. I omitted a column of table A that references another tables primary key (for the sake of simplicity, at least that is what I intended..)

Comment: An example would be really helpful here. Could your please update your question with samples of `A`, `B` and `C` to illustrate the data anomalies you are trying to avoid?